# Attribute help in an ER diagram

Tags: database, attributes, entity, diagram

I am creating an Entity Relationship diagram for a database to store recipe ingredients, the method to the recipe and the regulations for each ingredients according to the law. the purpose is to store the data to be tracked for a food safety audit.

bellow are the entities and their attributes.
i am unsure if i have created the attributes correctly.
any help is appreciated.

**Ingredients**
IngredientID
IngredientCategoryCode
IngredientName
IngredientUnitCost
IngredientManufactureDate
IngredientExpiryDate
IngredientDetails
SupplierID
RegulationID

**RefIngredientCategories**
RefIngredientCategoryID
IngredientCategoryCode
IngredientCategoryDescription
RegulationID

**Supplier**
SupplierID
SupplierName
SupplierAddress
SupplierEmail
SupplierPhone
SupplierContactName
RegulationID

**Product**
ProductID
ProductName
ProductDescription
ProductImage
ProductUnitCost
ProductSellByDate
ProductCreationDate
ProductTag
IngredientID
MethodID
RegulationID

**Measurement**
MeasurementID
MeasurementUnit
MeasurementQuantity

**Method**
MethodID
MethodName
MethodDescription
RegulationID

**MethodSteps**
MethodstepsID
MethodStepNumber
MethodStepInstructions
DerivedCostOfStep
RegulationID
IngredientID
MeasurementID

**Regulations**
RegulationID
RegulationDescription
IngredientCategoryID
SupplierID
MethodID
MethodStepID

**Batch**
BatchID
ProductID
BatchCreationDate
BatchExpiryDate
BatchSellByDate

Comment: What are you storing in the IngredientRegulations attribute?

Comment: RegulationID as the Primary key and RegulationDescription

Comment: Probably best if you list your entities and their attributes in your question, noting the FK relationships, instead of trying to give a narrative description.

Comment: i have done so, this is being created on filemaker so does not need FK. the PK's to each entity are the ID's

Comment: So what is your exact question?

Comment: okay, if each entity should have its own regulation attribute e.g. IngredientRegulation or if having the RegulationID attribute in that entity is sufficient.

Comment: Of course I don't know your domain, but if it makes sense for the same regulation to apply to different ingredients, then you should have a RegulationID in Ingredients. That way, when you update RegulationDescription that will change it for all ingredients.